# AppleScript grap JSON data from safari

Tags: json, safari, applescript

I have no knowledge at all about what I'm talking about which is a big issue.

I often run a search on an internal website, let say

> https://theexemplewebsite.demo/

I found out that searching with this pattern (XXXXXXX is my search keyword) I can retrieve the information I want in something which look like JSON (I think...)

> https://theexemplewebsite.demo/admin/api/v1/profil?id=XXXXXXX

e.g :

`{"aDate":11111,"bDate":111112,,"OtherData":false,"example":"D01","moreData":"DEMO","description":"OSX computer",`  and so on...

Is there a way to get this information, for example  OSX computer from "description":"OSX computer" and store them in a AppleScript variable ?

I hope that make some sense.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a valid JSON string you could use AppleScriptObjC – which provides access to Cocoa classes like `NSJSONSerialization` –  to parse it:

```
use framework "Foundation"

set jsonString to "{\"aDate\":11111,\"bDate\":111112,\"OtherData\":false,\"example\":\"D01\",\"moreData\":\"DEMO\",\"description\":\"OSX computer\"}"

set jsonNSString to current application's NSString's stringWithString:jsonString
set jsonData to jsonNSString's dataUsingEncoding:(current application's NSUTF8StringEncoding)
set {jsonDict, theError} to current application's NSJSONSerialization's JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 |error|:(reference)
if theError is missing value then
    set theDescription to jsonDict's |description| as text
    display dialog theDescription
else
    display dialog theError
end if
```